# In string.Format escape user entered characters such as {0), {1}

Tags: c#, .net

While sending an SMTP email I am getting the following error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

This error is specifically  happening because the entry.RunDescription has the following user entered text with some characters confusing the string.format method in email body.

```
pipettor ({0}) Test ({1}) Assay ({2}) Pack ({3}) Wedge ({4}) location ({5}) Final position ({6}) Maximum ({7})
```

Since this is a user entred text, Is there any way I could make it work besides adding logic that the user does not enter these characters or how could I escape these characters and still retain the text?

```
message.Body = string.Format(string.Format("<html><body>- Service Request<br/> A new service request is in queue <br/> Please use the following link to access the details of the Service Request <a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a> <br/>" +
entry.RunDescription +
"Thank you <br/> Administrator <br/></body></html>", ServiceRequestURL, Entry.ServiceEntryID));
```

Comment: Why message.Body = string.Format(string.Format("...")? This looks unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't "add" the user entered `entry.RunDescription` string to the **format string**. Instead add an additional parameter for it:

```
message.Body = string.Format(" ... <br/>{2} ...",
    ServiceRequestURL, Entry.ServiceEntryID, entry.RunDescription));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just concat the string outside format:

```
    message.Body = string.Format("<html><body>- Service Request<br/> A new service request is in queue <br/> Please use the following link to access the details of the Service Request <a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a> <br/>", 
   ServiceRequestURL, Entry.ServiceEntryID) +
   entry.RunDescription +
   "Thank you <br/> Administrator <br/></body></html>";
```

If you still want to escape, `{` should be repaced with `{{` and `}` should be replaced with `}}`